# How to automate the replacement of special characters in URLs?

Tags: 7, uri

The standard behavior **(*)** for friendly URLs in Drupal is replacing special characters by a hyphen in the friendly URL.

For instance,  *without any input from the user*, `versão` becomes `vers-o` and  `conteúdo` becomes `conte-do`. However, we need the character to be replaced by their corresponding non-accent ASCII values, such as `versao`  and `conteudo`.

Currently, we manually edit the URL when creating content. Is there a way to automate it?

---

**(*)**: I *assume* it's out-of-the-box behavior, but this Drupal instance had modules installed and configured by other persons, maybe it's not a default behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at the [Transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/project/transliteration) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> ... it takes Unicode text and tries to represent it in US-ASCII characters (universally displayable, unaccented characters) by attempting to transliterate the pronunciation expressed by the text in some other writing system to Roman letters.

As a sample, it transforms an URL like `mydomain.com/последние-новости-в-Украине-и-мире` in something like `mydoamin/poslednie-novosti-v-Ukraine-i-mire`.

However, to actually make this work, you also need to enable the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module. After that, go to the Pathauto setting page and check "Transliterate prior to creating alias". For more details on that, refer to "[D7 Pathauto transliteration](https://www.drupal.org/node/1163118)". **Attention**: this does not "fix" already created aliases (those need to be deleted and recreated).

Comment: I installed and tested it. It works only for file names.

Comment: I added the extra paragraph about the Pathauto module. Curious if that is how you can get it to work (also) ...

Comment: Seems like you got it to work, great! Thanks for accept also!

Comment: Yes, thanks A LOT for the tip! I really like it transliterates file names as well, it might prevent a lot of potential long-term issues with charsets and migrations =)

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to how Path Auto will create node paths? Regardless, there's good reason not to have [extended characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2) in your URL:

> The URI syntax has been designed with global transcription as one of
> its main considerations.  A URI is a sequence of characters from a
> very limited set: the letters of **the basic Latin alphabet, digits,
> and a few special characters.**  A URI may be represented in a variety
> of ways; e.g., ink on paper, pixels on a screen, or a sequence of
> character encoding octets.  The interpretation of a URI depends only
> on the characters used and not on how those characters are
> represented in a network protocol.

You can alter how Path Auto generates it's paths found at /admin/config/search/path/patterns

Comment: I don't want extended chars in URLs. I want, for instance, `conteúdo` changed to `conteudo` instead of `conte-do`.